# Keeping alive WCF process

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a long running process in WCF that takes 2-3 hours. The WCF runs for a long time after essentially the client that started the process leaves/times out. How long does it take for a WCF w3wp process to disappear since there was no connections to it. I'm thinking that even though the WCF is processing, it might stop WCF service because there was no new connection to it?

Comment: Have you tried this?  Does the WCF app get stopped even though it's processing? (I wouldn't expect it to).  We have run long running processes in IIS before without any issue with the processes being killed by timeouts, but admittedly we haven't done any that last for 2-3 hours.  IIS is surprisingly good at times at keeping AppDomains alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS will wait for the service operation to complete plus the [idle timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) minutes and then shut down the app pool.  The default idle timeout is 20 minutes.